# Finding route contains Source and Destination points

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have a problem with finding routes that are near (in range X km) the passed points (for e.x. A and B) in PostgreSQL PostGIS.

Example:
[image]

The point A denotes Source point and The point B denotes the Destination.

Tn system there are routes represented as LineString. I am also able to consider another ways to represent the routes.

Phere is no problem to find routes contains the points A and B in specific range (for e.x. 5 km):

```
SELECT * FROM routes
WHERE
    ST_Distance_Spheroid(route.lineString, 'POINT (long_A lat_A)', 'SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101]') < 5000
AND
    ST_Distance_Spheroid(route.lineString, 'POINT (long_B lat_B)', 'SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101]') < 5000
```

But there is the problem, that this query considers the path regardless its direction. It is insensitive to order the points that describes the linestring.

So there is a question. How select the routes contains points in specific range and consider order of points.

BTW: There is possible to represent routes as points and store in database the POINT and order number. So I can look for nearest points.

Comment: Why not use the pgrouting package to find routes? Pre-built route finding algorithms working through PostGIS/PostgreSQL seems an easy solution here.

Comment: I have no predefined routes or fragments. The routes are builded from the points returned from Google Maps. So pgrouting cannot be usefull for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i solved problem of ordering points based on `St_Line_Locate_Point` returned float value funtion.

Complete query:

```
SELECT ...
WHERE
        St_Line_Locate_Point(lineString, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(startPointLongitude startPointLatitude)'))
        < St_Line_Locate_Point(lineString, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(endPointLongitude endPointLatitude)'))
```